# Azure Web App local network communication

Tags: azure

I'm designing a micro service architecture hosted in Azure that will have the following .NET applications:

Azure Web App - MVC application
Azure web App - Web API application
Azure Web APp - Web API application
The MVC application will be the only one accessible through a web browser. When a user clicks a button, the MVC application will call one or both Web APIs (using REST calls).

Right now the Web APIs are accessed through their external urls (the ones hosted under .azurewebsite.net). The problem with this is that the traffic goes through the internet.

Is there a way for the MVC Application to call the Web APIs through a sort of "local network" so that there won't be delays due to the traffic going through the internet?

Thanks

PS: If this can't be achieved by using Azure Web Apps, can it be achieved with Azure Cloud Service? I know it can be achieved with IaaS, but I wouldn't want to take that route as it would require me to take care of all the IT stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of your services calls another service (in your case, your MVC app in a Web App calling a Web API in a Web App), and the two services reside in the same region, the traffic does not route through the internet; it stays within the region. Since the API has a publicly-accessible DNS entry point, you'd still need to deal with locking down the endpoints, from a security standpoint (however your app chooses to do this). But you won't need to worry about Internet latency between Web App and API.

You may also add a Web App to a Vnet and access any other services within that Vnet.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer David. So my assumption that the traffic goes through the internet was wrong :)